# I have created a DataFow in Azure Data Factory. In the sink , I need to add a time stamp to my filename

Tags: azure-data-factory

In the sink  filename, I need to add filename

**SampleFileName_dev_8Mar2023.tab**

In the Dataflow - Sink - Settings - Filename , I need to add the Dataflow expression builder.

What expression do I need to use to achieve above filename?

I tried to add the filename as below.
[image]

Under expressions tried this expression.
concat('SampleFileName ',toString(currentUTC('dd-MM-yyy')),'.tab').

But its not working

Comment: Is your Sink a Dataset or inline?

Comment: Sink is a Dataset

Comment: Do you want to add dynamically current date with filename?

Comment: yes actuallay. I tried to add a filename inside sink settings, Also used  expressions to add datetime stamp. But at this point my pipeline is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select **Output to single file** in Sink settings' File Name option.

[image]

- In the file Name, Click **Open expression builder**.

[image]

- Enter the expression as  `concat('SampleFileName_dev_',toString(dayOfMonth(currentUTC())),'-',toString(month(currentUTC())),'-',toString(year(currentUTC())),'.tab')`
- In optimize, Select **Single partition** as partition type.

[image]

- When the pipeline containing this  dataflow is executed, the file is created as expected.

[image]